# How to add_index in mysql2+rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

How do you add indexes in mysql2?

with line:
execute "alter table urli_development.slugs ADD INDEX slugs_sluggable_id(sluggable_id)"
everything works fine.

with line: add_index :slugs, :sluggable_id I get this 'Invalid date' error.

Problem is that I have to add following line:
add_index(:slugs, [:name, :sluggable_type, :sequence, :scope], :unique => true, :name => 'index_slugs_on_n_s_s_and_s')

Above line doesn't work.

I use Rails 3 and mysql2 and I get this 'Invalid date' error when I try to migrate database.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem too and to be quite frankly haven't got to a complete "why".But I do want to share something I just found out.

Try creating your table by excluding the "id" field....the add_index will run right away.So

```
class CreateSlugs < ActiverRecord::Migration   
    def self.up
      create_table :slugs,:id=>false do |t|             
         t.string "name"
         t.timestamps
       end
       add_index :indexes,"name",:name=>"slugs_name",:unique=>true
       add_column :slugs,:id,:primary_key
    end
end
```

Or if you wish to do it within a different migration

```
class AlterSlugs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self
    #add_index :slugs,:name,:unique
    #add_column :slugs,:id,:primary_key        
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

Actually is pretty interesting-> If you switch those two lines (add_index and add_column) ...**IT WON'T WORK!**

Answer (score 0):

you ran into [this bug](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dreamincode.net%2Fforums%2Ftopic%2F199581-rake-migration-failing-invalid-date%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFrqEzcOEWyBWQDBkU9ARweo3eKADA6AoA).

(I assume you're on Windows)
You can solve it by copying a fresh file:///C:/../mysql/lib/opt/libmysql.dll from your mysql 5.1 install to your Ruby/bin directory.

Then it works again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy and paste, "libmysql.ddl" anew into ruby's bin folder.

You can get it in the folder of Mysql Workbench if you have it installed in your machine or from alternative sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a previous version of the mysql gem instead of mysql2...

```
gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'
# gem 'mysql2'
```

I've run into this bug twice, in two different projects and this saved my day in both cases :)
It's also worth mentioning that add_index causes no trouble at all using mysql2 in Ubuntu. I guess this is a windows only issue.